# Proper way to declare field that needs to exist in sub-classes?

Tags: java, oop

Say I have a class `Animal` and then a bunch of sub-classes that extend `Animal`. Say I want to have a common field called `name` that should also exist in each child class. What is the proper way to include and initialize this field in each sub-class?

1) Declare the field in the parent as `protected`, and then initialize it inside of each sub-class. If I do it this way, is it proper to refer to the field as `super.variable` or simply `variable`? Personally to me, using super makes it more obvious that the field is declared in the parent. (This is what I am currently doing)

2) Declare the field in the parent as `private` and then create `getters` and `setters` to access the field

3) Just declare and initialize the same variable in each sub-class

4) Another method I'm missing?

Thanks for the help. I understand this question is fairly basic, but I'm curious of what the most proper style is.

**Edit:**

I'm not to sure if you guys will see this, but here is a follow up question.

Is there any good way to ensure that the sub-classes initialize the field?

Comment: Option 2 is preferred and standard; it's the safest way to ensure invariants are maintained as you can enforce them in the setter.

Comment: Have you considered removing the `name` field and making it an `abstract` method `name()` that must be overriden by subclasses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you need to control access to that field for correctness (e.g., to make sure that some other field gets updated at the same time). If it's okay for subclasses to twiddle the field directly, then just use `protected`. If you need to perform additional checks or actions whenever the field is set, you should make it `private` to the superclass and make the subclass use the setter to ensure your logic is run. You shouldn't duplicate the field if you know that it'll always be needed; if you're not sure, then you should consider using an `interface Animal` and putting the field on an `AbstractAnimal implements Animal`.

In Java, you don't use `super` for anything except to call the superclass's version of a method. Just access `protected` fields directly; that's what they're there for, and your development environment will keep track of where they're declared if you need to know.

Comment: I would argue there is nothing wrong with accessing a field like `super.field`.  This provides some context clues for other developers about where the field is declared.

Comment: Using `super` when you don't have a shadowing identifier is just extra wordiness. Any IDE will happily tell you where the field lives. That said, it is a style issue.

Comment: I agree its a styling thing.  An an IDE will tell you the origin of the field, however only after some work on the part of the developer. (Eclipse F3, ALT + Right Arrow)  Is there a quicker way in Eclipse or other IDEs?

Comment: On Eclipse, just hovering a field gives you the exact path where it's declared, its declared type, and any Javadoc attached to it.

Comment: I keep hearing that `super` should only be used to call a parent's method, but I just don't see any reasoning behind it. I know that you can use the IDE to get that info, but what's easier: hovering over each variable in a list of variables to see where it is declared, or simply look for `super`. I'm leaning towards the second every time.

Comment: @btse If you use the presence of the `super` keyword to determine where a field is declared, then you're relying on someone else to use the same atypical style; you can't trust that the lack of `super` means that it was declared in the same class, and so you're in the same position except with extra wordiness everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I vote for 2:

Create a private field, and have setters and getters (which can be protected to make them accessible only to subclasses).

Other options if you don't need a setter (just a getter):

4) Abstract getter and leave it up to the subclass how to implement it

5) private final field, set by abstract class constructor, and a getter.

Answer (score 2):

I always make fields `protected` fields, since this helps debuggability & extensibility, and put public getters & setters on them to make a 'property'.

(Private fields in various open-source libraries, Swing components etc have repeatedly been a hindrance to me when trying to do quite legitimate debugging/ extension engineering. So I'm fairly anti- them.)

If I'm concerned about traceability, where there is possible behaviour or errors involved (such as values being got & cached), I might access the variable in subclasses via the getter.

I always use `this.name` when *writing* to variables -- it works well for code clarity, and it simplifies parameter-naming in setters. (Use just `name` for the parameter & `this.name` for the field.)

I don't use `this` when *reading* variables -- it's the writes I want to be clear about. For collections, I suffix the *field* with List or map or whatever ie childList -- but the parameter and locals are "children".

I never use `super` when referring to variables. Super would only make sense to disambiguate inherited & declared variables *with the same name*, which you can legally do -- but is almost guaranteed to be erroneous for code style, clarity & tends to lead to bugs.

---

I also like to make most properties mutable -- rather than settable only at construction. This helps if you ever want to use Hibernate, or persist the data. Over-reliance on constructor initialization tends to evolve into difficulties -- large & brittle call-signatures, inability to use the class for partly-formed data or "special value" answers, and order-of-init problems.

Comment: Interesting, I like the idea of keeping it protected for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the situation.  If the name field should be publicly accessible, I would declare the field as private and then make public get/set methods.  Sometimes you want to expose fields on the base class as part of the public interface of the derived classes.

If the name field should only be used inside the derived classes I would just go with a protected field.

If you want to be sure that a subclass initializes a field add a parameter in the base class constructor, then initialize the field in the base class using the argument supplied by the derived classes constructor.

Comment: if you have get/set methods, why not make the field private?

Comment: How many times have I wanted to debug or extend something like the Swing grid, and been foiled in multiple ways by people making everything private. 'Private' has been a repeated problem for me in doing legitimate engineering, and I believe the Java guidelines are are least a partial failure in this respect.

Comment: Very rarely should a non-static field be directly publicly accessible.

Comment: @btse I added my thoughts about forcing implementation of a field in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

I usually using option 2 (private + accessors - protected,not necessary public) to have a chance to customize variable access.

About your edit: Force in constructor name if it is a mandatory requirement

```
Animal(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

or

```
String getName()  {
    if(null == name){
        name = initializeName();
    }
    return name;
}
```

and make `initializeName()` abstract